# What should be the scope of AmazonS3Client object in a web application?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net, requestscope

I want to use AWS SDK for .Net to read and write to an S3 bucket, from a web application.

What should be the scope of `AmazonS3Client` client?

Looking at [ASW sample code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html) they are using a `static s3Client`:

```
private const string bucketName = "*** provide bucket name ***";
private const string keyName = "*** provide a name for the uploaded object ***";
private const string filePath = "*** provide the full path name of the file to upload ***";
// Specify your bucket region (an example region is shown).
private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USWest2;
private static IAmazonS3 s3Client;
```

Can I create a `static` client, for the entire life-time of the application and use the same client for all the web requests?

Or should I create one client per request? i.e. the scope of the object is the web request (as in [this example](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Amazon.S3/AmazonS3Client/-/php-amazons3client-class-examples.html)):

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USWest2))
{
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
    {
        InputStream = imageStream,
        BucketName = BucketName,
        Key = key
    };

    client.PutObject(request);
    success = true;
}
```

If I use the later option, then the web application will potentially create multiple connections to the S3 bucket at the same time, because different users are using the website simultaneously).